# How to add new features to already trained model without training again on whole dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, feature-extraction, transfer-learning

Suppose, we have following features on which a classification model (Neural Network) is trained to predict whether a customer will buy Milk or not (0 :Will not buy, 1:Will buy) each week(n):

```
Feature1 Feature2 Feature3 Feature4
```

Now, after each week, we want to update the data for model by adding whether the customer bought milk in previous week or not (n-1).

Without using the time series, how can we update this information in our already trained model every week ?

- Can we add new features feature5, feature6 ... and so on every week,
  without training model on whole data, something like transfer
  learning ?

How can we best tackle this problem ?